# I am getting this error Attribute Error and I have checked for the typos but found none

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

AttributeError at /api-auth/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `UserDetailsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'.

my model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here


class UserDetails(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    virtualId = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import UserDetails


class UserDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = '__all__'
```

views :

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import UserDetails
from .serializers import UserDetailsSerializer

# Create your views here.


@api_view(['GET'])
def getAllUserdata(request):

    user = UserDetails.objects.all()
    serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing `querysets` so you must set `many=True` in your `serializers`.

From the `official` [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)

> To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the many=True

```
api_view(['GET'])
def getAllUserdata(request):

    user = UserDetails.objects.all()
    serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(user, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: oh yes thank you it worked :)

Comment: My pleasure @Divyansh Tamrakar. If it worked then mark this answer as `accepted answer`